# How is block different from mini panel?

Tags: 7, blocks, panels

I am a newbie in Drupal.

Can anybody explain how is block different from mini panel.

Comment: Not sure about the downvotes, this seems like a good question to me.  Drupal terminology is confusing and it's hard to learn, so it's better to explain it when we can.

Comment: Might be because the question is very light on details @PatrickKenny? Not sure what else could be provided to bulk it out though to be honest, seems to stand on its own for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mini panels allows you to use layouts, so you can have rows and columns within a mini panel block. Making life way easier when it comes to applying css.

In addition, it allows you to attach other things, such as views, other blocks, etc.. 
In contrast, if you use a regular block, you can only do one thing at a time with them.

So if you have lots of blocks, it can be messy if you want to change the block position. While if all the blocks are inside a mini panel, you can move them all at once.

Don't think of it as mini panel vs block. Think of it as mini panel being a block management system.